# get value of href tag through javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing

How do i get the value of the text between `>testhere</a>` in an href tag using javascript?

```
<a style="color:#39485;" href="/index.html">Hello, 112</a>
```

112 and /index.html will always be different, the only thing that will be the same is Hello, so having that in mind how do i get the value which in this case is 112? I don't want the Hello, part, just the 112. The number of digits may vary, it is not necessarily 3 digits long such as this one.
The line above that is:

```
<div id="nna">
```

and the one below is:

```
</span>
```

Another one is:

```
<a href="/index/page?number=33" class="page_number">
```

/index/page?number= will always be the same, and so will the class value.
The line above that is always:

```
<div id="mla">
```

the line below that always is:

```
<div class="friend_block_avatar">
```

Hopefully that will make it easier.
I want to get the number which will always be different which in this case is 33.
I will be running the javascript in my browser which is chrome through the url bar like this:javascript:javascriptcodegoeshere. So i cannot use jquery. The number of digits for this one may vary too, it is not necessarily 2 digits long.
Both of these will be in source code of the same page.

Comment: Do you have any control over the html at all?

Comment: No, i do not have control over the html.

Comment: How is this related to the style and href attributes? Are you just trying to get partial text content from anchors?

Comment: Quick note: if I recall correctly in the latest versions of Chrome you can't go `javascript:...` in the address bar anymore because of the Chrome XSS Auditor.

Comment: No, that is the whole point of being able to run javascript in chrome, chrome only blocks real reflected xss, not javascript run on the browser in that way.

Comment: @David i described everything to the best of my ability in my question.

Comment: @David To answer your question, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The first scenario:

Find all the anchors, then if the text starts with 'Hello, ' extract it:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    values = [],
    str = /Hello, /,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < anchors.length; i += 1) {
    if (str.test(anchors[i].text)) {
        values.push(anchors[i].text.replace(str, ''));
    }
}

console.log(values); // an array containing all the values
```

[Demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVmc4/1/)

## The second scenario:

Find all the anchors whose href begin with 'href="/index/page?number=' and extract the value:

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="/index/page?number="]'),
    values = [],
    i;

for (i = 0; i < anchors.length; i += 1) {
    values.push((anchors[i].pathname + anchors[i].search).replace('/index/page?number=', ''));
}

console.log(values); // an array containing all the values
```

[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVmc4/)

Comment: How do i alert the array?

Comment: @bob, you can replace `console.log` with `alert` if you want, but it is better to use `console.log`.

Comment: I added more details, it should be easier now.

Comment: @bob, you're right, sorry. I had a couple of typos. This now works.

Answer (score 0):

Find all of the anchors first:

```
var anchors = document.links;
```

Then parse through them and split up by what makes them unique: `Hello,`:

```
if(anchors.length > 0) {
    for(var i in anchors) {
        var str = anchors[i].innerText;

        if(undefined !== str) {
            var parts = str.split('Hello, ');

            if(parts.length > 0 && parts[0] === '') {
                console.log(parts[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this sample data:

```
<a style="color:#39485;" href="/index.html">Hello, 112</a>
<a style="color:#39485;" href="/index1.html">Hello, 113</a>
<a style="color:#39485;" href="/index2.html">Hello, 114</a>
<a style="color:#39485;" href="/index3.html">113</a>
<a href="/index/page?number=33" class="page_number">Hello, 123</a>
```

...your console will show `112`, `113`, `114` and `123`.

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ByZhX/)**

Comment: Sorry, i just want a quick script that can parse both of those values directly into a variable. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: I added more details, it should be easier now.

Answer (score 0):

**Assumptions**: you want any number of digits in the `href` and html of all anchor tags on the page.

You can execute the following from the OmniBar in chrome (you do know that you can use Chrome's built in console to execute javascript on the current page right?).

```
javascript: var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a'); anchors.forEach = [].forEach; function grabDigits (string) { var match = string.match(/\d+/); if (match && match[0]) { return match; } } anchors.forEach(function(anchor){ console.log('text: ' + grabDigits(anchor.innerHTML)); console.log('href: ' + grabDigits(anchor.href)); }); /* run with: javascript: var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a'); anchors.forEach = [].forEach; anchors.forEach(function(anchor){ match = anchor.innerHTML.match(/\d+/); if (match && match[0]) { console.log(match[0]); } }); */
```

Chrome may strip the initial `javascript:` bit, so you may need to type that in manually into the omnnibar and then copy and paste the rest of the script.

I'm freewheeling a litle bit here, but it seems to be working ^^:

**JS**

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');

anchors.forEach = [].forEach;


function grabDigits (string) {
  var match = string.match(/\d+/);
  if (match && match[0]) { 
    return match;
  }
}

anchors.forEach(function(anchor){
  console.log('text: ' + grabDigits(anchor.innerHTML));
  console.log('href: ' + grabDigits(anchor.href));

});
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ixavel/1/edit)

Comment: Not of all anchor tags, only those. You're the closest to completing this one.

Comment: I added more details, it should be easier now.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `href` and `innerHTML` prefixes will always be the same, and you are simply looking for a number following, you can accomplish this with a simple regular expression. Example:

HTML:

```
<a style="color:#39485;" href="/index.html">Hello, 112</a>
<a href="/index/page?number=33" class="page_number">some link</a>
<a href="index.html">Should not be included</a>
```

JS:

```
var regex = /.*number=(\d+)|Hello,\s(\d+)/
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var innerHtmlNumbers = [];
var hrefNumbers = [];
for (var index = 0; index < links.length; index++) {
  var link = links[index];
  var match = regex.exec(link.getAttribute("href")); // Check the href first
  if (match) {
    // Found an href like "/index/page?number=12381239"
    var hrefNumber = match[1];
    hrefNumbers.push(hrefNumber);
  } else {
    // Check innerHTML for something like "Hello, 123813912"
    match = regex.exec(link.innerHTML);
    if (match) {
      var innerHtmlNumber = match[2];
      innerHtmlNumbers.push(innerHtmlNumber);
    }
  }
}
console.log(hrefNumbers);
console.log(innerHtmlNumbers):
```

Take a [look at this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4jYke/2/) to see a working example. With this, you can simply run through all of your `<a>` tags at once.

Comment: I added more details, it should be easier now.

Answer (score -2):

Im not sure that i understood your question correct  - you want to cut the number from the other content? You could do this with string.split: when you have a string with a breakpoint for example

a = "Hello,112"

You could do something like this:

a.split(",") will return an array with:

{"Hello,","112"}

I hope i understood it right ^^

Comment: Read my question and comments again, this has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Wait - why the downvotes and so unfriendly? Jtery answered the same thing.